Skip Button Not Responding in Onboarding Screen (Flutter)
I am developing a mobile app and currently working on the onboarding screen, which consists of 3 introductory screens. The skip button on my onboarding screen is not responding at all. I have tried several solutions, including wrapping the button with different widgets (Container, TextButton, GestureDetector), but none of them have resolved the issue.
Here is my code:
import 'package:dots_indicator/dots_indicator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:hr_app/resources/String_manager.dart';
import 'package:hr_app/resources/color_manager.dart';
import 'package:hr_app/resources/values_manager.dart';
import 'package:hr_app/view/screens/login_view/loginScreenView.dart';
import 'package:hr_app/view/screens/onboarding_view/pageParts/PageView.dart';
import '../../../resources/Font_Manager.dart';
import '../../../resources/size_config.dart';
import '../../common/CustomButton.dart';

class onBoardingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const onBoardingScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<onBoardingScreen> createState() => _onBoardingScreenState();
}

class _onBoardingScreenState extends State<onBoardingScreen> {
  PageController? controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = PageController(initialPage: 0) ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: SizeConfig.defaultSize! * 7,
            right: AppSize.s40,
            child: Opacity(
              opacity: (controller!.hasClients) && (controller!.page == 2) ? 0.0 : 1.0,
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print("skip button has been clicked");
                  // Get.to(()=> const LogScreen());
                },
                child: Text(
                  StringManager.onBoardingPageSkip,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: FontSize.s14,
                    color: ColorManager.primaryColor,
                  ),
                  softWrap: false,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 0, right: 0,
            bottom: SizeConfig.defaultSize! * 20,
            child: DotsIndicator(
              dotsCount: 3,
              position: (controller!.hasClients ? controller!.page! : 0).toInt(),
              decorator: DotsDecorator(
                shape: CircleBorder(
                  side: BorderSide(color: ColorManager.primaryColorDark, width: 1.5, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                ),
                color: Colors.transparent,
                activeColor: ColorManager.primaryTextColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // specify the height here
          Page_view(controller),
          Positioned(
            left: SizeConfig.defaultSize! * 10,
            right: SizeConfig.defaultSize! * 10,
            bottom: SizeConfig.defaultSize! * 10,
            child: CustomGenralButton(
              text: (controller!.hasClients) && (controller!.page == 2)
                  ? StringManager.onBoardingPageGetStarted
                  : StringManager.onBoardingPageNext,
              onTap: () {
                // print("button has been clicked");
                if (controller!.page != 2) {
                  controller!.nextPage(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    curve: Curves.easeIn,
                  );
                } else if (controller!.page! == 2) {
                  Get.to(() => const LogScreen());
                }
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

What I've Tried
Wrapping the skip button in a Container
Using TextButton instead of GestureDetector
Using GestureDetector for the skip button
None of these attempts have made the skip button responsive. The button appears on the screen, but tapping it does not trigger any action.
Question
What could be causing the skip button to be unresponsive, and how can I fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

change textbutton to elevated button or Wrap whole widget in InkWell widget

debug it to find out which widget is actually causing the issue. try removing the opacity around text button, sometimes other widgets in the stack capture the gestures just comment out the other widgets in stack and check if it is working or not

Firstly, you have to deal with the opacity widget and know that.
For the value 0.0, the child is not painted at all, i think your condition should be reversed:
opacity: (controller!.hasClients) && (controller!.page == 2) ? 1 : 0,

if it's still not working try to remove opacity widget, i recommend avoid using it because it's relatively expensive, try to use a container instead of it:
Container(
 color: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1), // last parameter for opacity
 child: YourButton()
)


thank you very much, brother. your advice fixed my issue
